# Java/Oracle: executing a prepared statement fails on a second iteration of a loop (not all variables bound). Why?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, oracleclient

I'm debugging a Java App, which connects to Oracle DB via a thin client.

The code looks as follows: (i'm trying to simplify the use case here so pardon me if t does not actually comile)

```
Connection conn = myEnv.getDbConnection();
CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall(
         "{ ? = call SomePackage.SomeFunction (?)}");
call.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
for (int runCount = 0; runCount <= 1; runCount++) {
    currency = getCurrency(runCount); // NOTE: [0]=CAD, [1]=USD
    call.setString(2, currency);
    try { call.execute(); } catch { // BREAKS HERE! }
    ResultSet rset = (ResultSet)call.getObject(1);
    ... more code that I think is irrelevant as it does not use/affect "call"
}
```

When I run this code, the following happens:

- First iteration of the loop, `currency` is set to "CAN".
- Entire code of the loop runs perfectly fine.
- Second iteration of the loop,`currency` is set to "USD".
- The `"execute()"` call throws SQLException, as follows:

  `ORA-01008: not all variables bound`

**Why?**

My initial suspicion was that it somehow related to `registerOutParameter` call before the loop that doesn't get called on 2d iteration. But moving that call inside the loop does not fix the problem. It seems that `execute()` call un-binds something but having both bindings inside the loop does not help.

What am I missing?

If it's something obvious, please be gendle - I know very little about Oracle and thin client, and Googling witrh miriad of fancy queries returned no love.

One additional clue: this design seemed to have worked before when the app was on Oracle 9 with OCI drivers. The reason I'm debuggin it is someone "upgraded" it to Oracle 10.2 thi client and it broke.

My next step should probably be bringing in entire `CallableStatement` into the loop, but that kind of defeats the whole idea of why I though prepared statements are used in the first place, no?

Comment: Does it help if you put the registerOutputParameter() into the loop with the setString()?

Comment: Sadly, as I said in the Q, it does not :(

Comment: Are you using the latest driver? http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/htdocs/jdbc_10201.html

Comment: oracle client version is 10.2.0 from what I can see in directory path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation obtained via Oracle Support call was that this version of Java (1.3) was not compatible with new Oracle. Java 1.4 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `call.clearParameters()` into the loop? Perhaps it would reset some internal state on the object that it needs to execute again.